# Is there the concept of a wiki in Visual Studio 2013 online?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, wiki, azure-devops

I've had a browse around the Visual Studio 2013 online capabilities but can't see any wiki as such. By wiki I mean somewhere to capture enduring product related info e.g. info on how to support product xyz, how to setup a new dev workstation, how to workaround that annoying "msshrtmi.dll" Azure bug that continually crops up. Stuff like that.

Currently using Google sites wiki which is awful!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unfortunately the Visual Studio Online does not support wiki for project now. I miss this feature too. You can [vote for the feature](http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/2948957-integrate-team-wiki-project-documentation-pages) on uservoice to accelerate its development.

**Update:** Issue is completed on 9 January 2015. Thanks to developers and to all who voted. For more information, see  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bharry/archive/2014/12/18/improved-welcome-wiki-experience.aspx

Comment: That's a shame. It's a pretty critical part of an effective development team. I imagine many dev shops fail to utilize such a capability as it's not included in the Microsoft stack. Others like us, wind up using some inferior product that offers no integration with other dev tools. Will vote as you suggest. Thanks.

Answer (score 14):

We have launched a set of features to enable a Markdown-based project documentation solution. Users can now edit and create their VSO project docs right in the browser.

Do check out our blog post and video here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bharry/archive/2014/12/18/improved-welcome-wiki-experience.aspx

Let us know if you have any comments on the features!

Yi-Wei Ang
Program Manager
VSO Enterprise Social

Comment: Thanks, I just found out about this functionality via this blog post: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2015/01/19/markdown-in-visual-studio-online.aspx (link has a bit more info)

Answer (score 0):

There is now a Wiki from Microsoft DevLabs for Visual Studio Team Services in the Visual Studio Marketplace. At the time of writing it is still in beta. When it is finished it will be installed as an integral part of Visual Studio Team Services.

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-devlabs.wiki

Answer (score 0):

As of 7/6/2017, Microsoft has released the public preview of the Visual Studio Team Services Wiki. The Visual Studio Marketplace extension has now been deprecated.

You can read more about the capabilities of the Wiki in VS TS here:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devops/2017/07/06/33855/